# Coherence Value of 0.3 in LDA Model

Tags: lda, topic-modeling

I am having some confusion over the use of coherence score in evaluating LDA model.

I had run an LDA model on a dataset and have obtained coherence score ranging from 0.32 to 0.37 and perplexity score ranging from -6.75 to -6.77 for a various number of topics.

I am using the LDA model in the gensim package and this is the code which I use to calculate the coherence score.

```
coherencemodel = CoherenceModel(model=lda_model, texts=texts, dictionary=id2word, 
coherence='c_v')
coherenceScore = coherencemodel.get_coherence()
```

I had always understood that the use of coherence score is to find the optimal number of topics used in the LDA model. But I was also told that a coherence score of 0.3 is bad.

Can someone kindly explain what is coherence score used for and does a score 0.3 signifies a bad model? 
And when we are comparing between different LDA models, which is the better evaluation method, perplexity or coherence score?

Comment: Hi there. This question isn't answerable as asked. First, there are many different coherence metrics. Which one are you using? Second (which could actually end up answering the first question) what software are you using? Gensim for Python? topicmodels for R? MALLET for Java?

Comment: Hi! I'm using Gensim for Python.

Comment: Ok. Gensim has a bunch of coherence scores.  https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/coherencemodel.html Any idea which one you're using?

Comment: Also, FWIW, my impression of perplexity is that its magnitude depends on your corpus, so that there may not be a universally "good" or "bad" measure. The same may hold for many coherence measures. The one that I tend to use (in the textmineR package for R) is bound between -1 and 1. Therefore 0.3 (overall) would be pretty good.

Comment: Thanks for the response! So am I right to say that since coherence measures depend on my corpus, so trying different parameters in the LDA model would not actually give us much difference in terms of the coherence score? And it should not be used as a measure to compare with other LDA model that uses a different corpus?